# Azure SQL blob storage select

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, openrowset

I am attempting to create a temp table to store the values of an `xlsx` file on my azure blob storage, I have followed numerous Microsoft articles now and I am under the impression that I should be using `SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET()`, this seems to be working or at least selecting something.

**Here is my code:**

```
SELECT * INTO ##TempTest FROM OPENROWSET(BULK  'test.xlsx',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'DevStoreAccount', SINGLE_CLOB) AS a;

SELECT * FROM ##TempTest
```

This all runs fine, but the output *is not what I am expecting*, surely this should return all my columns / rows from the excel file? Or am I mistaken?

**The above code returns the following:**

[image]

What exactly is it returning and should I be doing something different? Any help would really be appreciated.

I'm trying this route as the columns in the excel file could change at any time, so I need to dynamically create my tables.

Comment: *as the columns in the excel file could change at any time, so I need to dynamically create my tables.*  -- Potentially unhelpful remark on my part here, but personally I refuse as much as possible to try and automate these scenarios.  Can you not push back on getting a consistent import format?

Comment: @iamdave As much as I would like to use a static group of headers, unfortunately I cant.. It is an excel document generated from a CRM, so the user can select whichever columns they want :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking this [thread](https://debugmode.net/2011/08/28/creating-and-updating-excel-file-in-windows-azure-web-role-using-open-xml-sdk/), although the post is old, it is still relevant to your question.
The approach taken for the similar scenario:

1- Create and update Excel file using Open XML SDK

2- Upload Excel Template in Azure BLOB

3- Download Excel template in azure web role local storage

4- Read and update excel file from azure web role local storage

5- Upload updated excel in Azure BLOB.

**II**
You could also use another similar concept as mentioned [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/fd753250-493e-4f14-9a1f-e8a9926385c6/creating-and-uploading-excel-file-using-open-xml-sdk-to-azure-blob?forum=windowsazuredata)

1. Downloading excel file as Stream from BLOB
2. Creating Excel document using Open XML SDK
3. After edit saving doc to Stream
4. Uploading back the Stream to BLOB